# Fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{x_1, x_2\}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

For $M = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{x\}$, you can calculate $\pi_1$ using the fact that you can retract $M$ onto a circle, s.t. $\pi_1(M)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. But how can you calculate the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{x_1, x_2\}$? And is there any rule for the $n$-punctured plane?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem is the way

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: you can deformation retract the plane minus $n$ distinct points onto the wedge of $n$ circles.

Comment: Beautiful. And is this Z + Z or do I see it wrongly?

Comment: No, going around one of the circles is not homotopic to going around another circle. Per @Exodd's comment, you need to use the Seifert-van Kampen theorem.